# Hibernate. Локализация. Динамическая загрузка

Tags: java, hibernate, локализация

У меня есть таблица "Страны" со столбцами:

```
id, en, de, fr, ru, lt

id - PK
en,de,... - перевод названия страны
```

Я хочу создать Entity с полем "название страны"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class EntityCountry {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Localization
    private String name;
```

И получить его с помощью локали en, de,...

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
EntityCountry e = (EntityCountry) session.createQuery("from EntityCountry where id = 1").setLocalization("en").uniqueResult();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Как это можно сделать?